# qt png in resource corrupted after static linking

Tags: qt, qt4

We're developing a quite large Qt-based project on linux, and we reached final RC1 stage.

Now, we encountered something really strange: in order to go into production, we added another .a library in our list of static linking libs.

The library is linked and the application runs, but every .png in the resource file is corrupted, here's the output on startup:

libpng error: IHDR: CRC error

seems like libpng cant handle those invalid png (of course). The files are there and the size is right, they just turned blank after static linking that final library. The library itself is not used anywhere, it is just linked.

Has anyone encountered such a situation before? is there a known workaround? We're using Qt 4.7.4 x64 on QtCreator 2.3.0, we would like not to upgrade for now, but it is the only option that comes into our mind for now.

Comment: Does changing the optimisation settings affect it?  It may be worth creating an isolated environment with the latest Qt version, and building just to see if it is a Qt problem rather than a compiler/libpng problem.

Comment: switching to Qt 4.8.1 / QtCreator 2.4.1 and disabling optimization produced no results

Comment: tried removing & re-adding png in resource, no effect. Crash @ QImage(":/icons/<whatever>.png").constBits(); strange is that every other non-png files in resource are fine. Tried to force qrc not to use compression at all (even if png are under 70% default thereshold) no effect. QImage(<path>) returns an empty QImage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could fit a problem with symbols.
The static library and libpng could be at same time linking to other library and when linking or resolving in compile/load time something weird is happening.

You can use *objdump* command to inspect symbols (objdump -tT /usr/bin)

Have you tried modifying the library order when compiling/linking? I mean, for example,

```
gcc -lmylibrary -lQt -lOtherLOLibrary
```

instead of

```
gcc -lOtherLOLibrary -lQt -lmylibrary
```

And I think I'm missing something, why do you link against an unused library?

Comment: of course it is not intended to be left unused, it _will_ be used as soon as we'll resolve this integration issue. It has been left unused for debugging purposes.

Comment: Perfect, now it's clear. But, now, just changing this compilation library "flag" makes the difference between working and not?

Comment: changing flags order produces no effect. I noticed objdump states both <ourlib>.a AND libpng.so declare: 000000000000 DF_UND 0000000000 crc32 (in libpng), and in <ourlib>.a 00000000000000 F .text 0000000000002e crc32 maybe there is conflict on internal variable (called crc32)?

Comment: unfortunately we have no control over it, already contacted the team but didnt get any answer, nor do we know if it is feasible, or if they will change it.

Comment: okay we discarded libpng and switched to tiff converting every png, not elegant but surely faster (we have only 25 png) than having someone to rewrite something TY anyway

Comment: Thanks. Had the same problem and it was a pain to debug even with this hint. Not sure what I would do without it. Libpng (used internally by Qt) defines public crc32 (imported from libz I think) and we had our own crc32 with different signature in our dynamic library. When we linked with it, suddenly all PNG icons in Qt went missing and above message was printed to console.